# How do you count the sections of the unit circle $0$, $\pi/2$, $\pi$, $3\pi/2$, $2\pi$, $2\pi/2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am a confused as to how the unit circle is calculated as you rotate around it. I am currently looking at a sine chart and they have it labeled $2.5\pi, 3\pi, 3.5\pi$ and $4\pi$.

While I understand $3\pi$ and $4\pi$. I don't understand how $2.5\pi$ and $3.5\pi$ were calculated- For example, if I wanted to figure out what came after $4\pi$, would it be $\frac{4\pi}{2}$? Can someone explain how the unit circle is broken up. I believe my professor said the circle is split into $\frac{1}{4}$ but I am not sure.

Comment: For every quarter of a revolution in the counterclockwise direction, add $\pi/2$.  Thus, a quarter revolution past two full revolutions is $4\pi + \pi/2 = 9\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

A full circle is $2\pi $ radians.  Everything else you ask should be scaled in terms of that.  $3 \pi$ is once and a half around the circle, $4 \pi$ is twice around.  $2.5\pi$ is a circle and a quarter, so $\frac \pi 2$ more than a full circle.  There is no answer to what is after $4 \pi$, just like there is no answer to what is after $0$.  It is one of whatever the smallest unit you are considering.

Comment: Okay. Lets say I am have a graph y=sin(x/2) what would the corresponding points be where the graph is -1 and how did you arrive at those numbers. Did you just add a certain number and perform simple addition with fractions?

Comment: That is right.  The points where $\sin (x/2)=-1$ are $\frac {3\pi}2 + 2k\pi$ for $k$ any integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you seem to have a penchant for speaking Grengish. Instead of pronouncing $\pi$ as "pi", try pronouncing $\pi$ as "half rotation". By translating like this instead of $2.5$ pi, $3$ pi, $3.5$ pi and $4$ pi we have $2.5$ half rotations, $3$  half rotations, $3.5$  half rotations, and $4$ half rotations (with $0.5$ half rotations being just a quarter rotation).